# How to calculate all the combinations of lists

Tags: python, list, combinations

I am blocked on a Python problem and hope someone could help me.

The problem is prety simple actually.

Im trying to build lists with all combination possible but the elements of the list have not the same range.

here is my code, I tried to do something with for loop but it doesnt work.

```
for j in range(0,size):


    for k, val in enumerate(self.Algo.Inputs[j].Values):
        self.Commandlist[j] = k
```

self.Commandlist is a list with fix range, and fill with zero at first.

self.Commandlist = [0,0,0]

self.Algo.Inputs[j].Values gives me the size of each elements, for example, if self.Algo.Inputs[0].Values = 4
   self.Algo.Inputs[1].Values = 1
   self.Algo.Inputs[2].Values = 2

i want all the combinations, [0,0,0],[1,0,0],[2,0,0],[3,0,0],[4,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,1,0],[2,1,0],[3,1,0],[4,1,0] etc..

I think I forgot a loop but i cant figure out. I tried some stuff with itertools module as well, but i cant make it work.

Thans for your help.

Comment: For the expected output you want all possible combinations of range(x)..eg 0,1,...x-1; 1,0,2,....x-1; etc?

Comment: You may wish to use the `itertools` module.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned you can use itertools, for example like that:

```
import itertools
a = b = c = range(3) # you can specify different range for each one
[list(x) for x in list(itertools.product(a, b, c))]
```

Result:

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [0, 2, 2], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 0], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 0, 0], [2, 0, 1], [2, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 0], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need. Meanwhile, the number of elements and their range are variables. it is possible to do that with loop I guess ?